# Besides memory management, what's a QObject's parent used for?

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I know that, when a [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) is destroyed, it also destroys all of its children. But, in all my recent Qt code, I've always been declaring the members of any class (say, a [`QMainWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html)) as direct members, not pointer members, which makes Qt's memory management rarely (if at all) useful.

So, is this parenting property of [`QObjects`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) used for something else? <s>From the documentation, it isn't clear if [`QBoxLayout::addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) takes ownership of the widget (I think it doesn't).</s> (When you add widgets to a layout, [their parent will be set to the parent of the layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts), as [thuga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257050/thuga), pointed out).

Comment: When you add widgets to a layout, [their parent will be set to the parent of the layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts) (the widget that contains the layout).

Comment: Besides destruction reasons, one good reason to set a parent is when you move objects to a new thread. When you move an object to a new thread, it moves all of its children to the new thread as well.

Comment: Your usage of Qt classes in no idiomatic. I suggest to use Qt classes as documentation proposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other uses that come to mind:

- when using `moveToThread()`, an entire object tree gets moved, not just the pushed object (otherwise, memory management becomes impossible);
- `QWidget` extends the parent/child relation with new semantics, for instance:

  - children's coordinates are relative to the parent widget;
  - a parent widget will clip its children to its own geometry;
  - the order of the sibling widgets determines their z-ordering (stacking);
  - unhandled mouse/keyboard events propagate up in the hierarchy;
  - the parent of a top-level widget will make that top-level share the same taskbar entry and appear centered on top of the parent (typical case: dialogs).