# QSqlTableModel database connection issue

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

Reading the [QSqlTableModel documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) I see two ways to get the model:

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
```

and

```
QSqlTableModel model;
```

Which database connection is chosen in the second case? Do I need an active connection at this point?

I tried the second, making `QSqlTableModel model` a class member.

```
class MyClass {
    QSqlTableModel model;
public:
    MyClass(){}
public slots:
    onDbConnected(){
        model.setTable("employee");
        bool b = model.select();  
    }
};
```

But `model.select()` returns `false` this way.

Should I, instead, do (in the body of the slot - not making model a class member)?

```
 QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Which database connection is chosen in the second case?

**The default database connection is chosen.** From [`QSqlTableModel`'s constructor documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#QSqlTableModel), you can see that if you don't specify a `db` argument, it will default to [`QSqlDatabase()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#QSqlDatabase)(which is an empty invalid `QSqlDatabase`object):

> If db is not valid, the default database connection will be used.

The default connection is defined when calling [`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) without specifying a *connectionName* parameter.

---

> ### Do I need an active connection at this point?

Both forms require a valid database connection to be used by the model. You can have a look at the [Table Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-tablemodel-example.html) for an example on how to use the class.

Usually, You have to set up the database connection at application startup. After that, you can use this connection in any `QSqlQuery`/`QSqlQueryModel`/`QSqlTableModel`. . .

---

> ### Should I, instead, do (in the body of the slot - not making model a class member)?

If your goal is just to pass arguments to a member object's constructor, you don't need to allocate the object dynamically. This is a general C++ connection, you can pass whatever arguments you need in your `MyClass`'s constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    QSqlTableModel model;
public:
    MyClass(): model(this, QSqlDatabase::database("mydbconnection")){}
...
```

Both approaches should do the job. Choosing one over the other does not have to do anything with the `select()` call failing. Personally, I would prefer avoiding dynamic allocation if it is not really needed. You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39931734/2666212) for a similar comparison.

---

> ### `model.select()` returns `false`

Here are some suggestions that may help figuring out the problem:

1. Check that the **database connection was `open()`** before constructing the `QSqlTableModel`.
2. Check that you haven't provided a **wrong table name** in [`setTable()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setTable).
3. you can use [`model.lastError()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#lastError) to get more information about the error.

   ```
   qDebug() << model.lastError();
   ```

Comment: In my app the db connection is established by the user after app start up. Considering this, there is no point in having `model` as a class member, since during start up there will be no connection. Am I right?

Comment: @KcFnMi deciding whether you should use a class member vs dynamic allocation, is not related to the way you setup your database connection. Again, *Both forms require a valid database connection to be used by the model*. Establishing the database connection at application startup is not required (I just said it's the usual way), the only requirement would be that the connection [is open](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#isOpen) before you use your model.